# Why do you need to declare the generic type in a void static method signature in JAVA?

Tags: java, generics

Why do I have to follow static with the used Generic class for the following piece of code to compile?

```
public static<Integer>void main(String args[]){

        BinaryTree<Integer> tree = new BinaryTree<Integer>();

}
```

Comment: You don't. Your assumption is false.

Comment: Does your class begin `class BinaryTree<Integer> { ... ` by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that what you are trying to do is define a `BinaryTree` class whose nodes are of type `Integer`, and so you have written something like this.

```
public class BinaryTree<Integer> {

    // Code

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BinaryTree<Integer> tree = new BinaryTree<Integer>();
    }
}
```

In the above code, `Integer` does not have its usual meaning. Because it appears in angular brackets after the class name, it is in fact it is a type parameter. Normally type parameters have single-letter names, but the name `Integer` is allowed.

Because the `main` method is static (belongs to the class, not an individual instance of the class), it does not have access to the type parameter. That is why the code for `main` does not compile.

By writing

```
publie static <Integer> void main(String args[])
```

instead, you are making the `main` method generic. The type parameter for the method (again called `Integer`!) hides the type parameter for the class, and the code compiles.

To fix the problem you can either make the class have type paramter `T`, or simply remove the class type parameter completely (if all `BinaryTree` instances have type `Integer`, there is no need for the class to be generic at all).

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way this could fail to compile could be that you are having something like this

```
public class Test<Integer> {
     public static<Integer> void main(String args []){
        Map<Integer, String> aHash = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    }
}
```

and you are using "Integer" as a type parameter (which is legal although probably not the best idea)

Now this would work for non-static methods, i.e.

```
public class Test<Integer> {
     public  void main(String args []){
        Map<Integer, String> aHash = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    }
}
```

would compile fine, but for static methods, the class type parameter cannot be used as you would make a static reference to the non-static type parameter.